# Has anyone measure the strength of the force of gravity in relation to the molecular bonding?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, quantum-gravity

It's clear to me that gravity it a function of mass. It is also clear to me that gasses are less affected by gravity. So I'm thinking that there exists a measurable minimum binding distance $d$ between molecules that determines whether the molecules will collectively experience a gravitational pull.

In other words, for the same element molecules $M_1$ and $M_2$ the gravitational force is normally represented by the addition of both masses ($M_1 + M_2$). But when $M_1$ and $M_2$ exceed a distance $d$ of separation, the mass used to determine the gravitational force is just $M_1$ or $M_2$. Then if there were a molecular bond that separates the molecules by a distance greater than $d$, gravity could be nullified.

Is this possible or am I totally off base?

Comment: The short answer is that gravitational corrections to the electrostatic forces in molecular bonds are waaay beyond the precision limits of today's measurement technology and theory.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic. The help center says: "Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: [..] Pitches for your own personal theories or work
We deal with mainstream physics here. Anything that couldn't be published in a reputable journal is not appropriate on this site."

Comment: I'm gonna vote to close as well because I really don't think there's more to say on the matter beyond my previous comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70202/2451

Comment: David thanks! I'm new to this field. All I have is a Mechanical Engineering degree. I took some advance Physics classes as electives, but stayed out of touch with it. This was just a burning question in my head. I guess I need to get up to speed in this technology field. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're pretty off-base here. You said:

> It is also clear to me that gasses are less affected by gravity.

This isn't true. Gasses are affected by gravity just like everything else. If gases weren't affected by gravity, the earth's atmosphere would escape out into space.

Why isn't the entire atmosphere condensed and sitting on the ground? Well, the air around the earth has a lot of kinetic energy by virtue of it's temperature. All of these molecules banging around creates *pressure*. The pressure decreases with height, such that the force from the pressure gradient cancels out the force of gravity exactly.

Comment: A good keyword to look for relating to that last sentence is "hydrostatic equilibrium".